# How to wait v-for and then execute slick slider

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-component, slick.js

I have the laravel 5.3 installed and vuejs component, here's the code

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" v-for="item in options">
            <other-component/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import OtherComponent from './OtherComponent.vue'

    export default {
        name: 'TopProductView',
        updated() {
            $('#id').slick()
        }
        computed: {
            options() {
                ...
            }
        },
        components: {
            OtherComponent,
        },
        ...
    }

</script>
```

The problem is, i need to wait the v-for complete the loop of other component and then call the [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) slider. how do i do that?

As far as i try the slick always called first, or called before the loop is complete

Answer (score 0):

You can watch the computed property instead of the component updated hook

```
watch: {
    options() {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
            $('class').slick()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for fast reply, but i'm still has the issue. 
the slick slider still not waiting the loop
i forgot to mention that the OtherComponent has a ajax request and image

Comment: Can you do the ajax call in your component and pass data to OtherComponent instead?